# have the uploaded files landing in a specific folder and getting the url of the uploaded file (all in google drive)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

So guys i have this upload form that is on google apps script. the upload is working just fine and they are landing in drive successfully after uploading.

I need the files to land in a certain folder lets say "folderX", and after the upload is complete i want it to return a URL of the item inside the drive(for edit purposes or management...idk).

If this doesnt work or cant work, i need it to be uploaded to a database, lets say the db name is dbupload, the table name is dbuploadtable and it has id, name, url.

here is my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Resumable upload for Web Apps</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
    </form>
    <div id="progress"></div>

<script>
    const chunkSize = 5242880;

    $('#uploadfile').on("change", function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        if (file.name != "") {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.fileName = file.name;
            fr.fileSize = file.size;
            fr.fileType = file.type;
           fr.onload = init;
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
    });

    function init() {
        $("#progress").text("Initializing.");
        var fileName = this.fileName;
        var fileSize = this.fileSize;
        var fileType = this.fileType;
        console.log({fileName: fileName, fileSize: fileSize, fileType: fileType});
        var buf = this.result;
        var chunkpot = getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize);
        var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buf);
        var chunks = chunkpot.chunks.map(function(e) {
            return {
                data: uint8Array.slice(e.startByte, e.endByte + 1),
                length: e.numByte,
                range: "bytes " + e.startByte + "-" + e.endByte + "/" + chunkpot.total,
            };
        });
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(at) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + at);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            mimeType: fileType,
            name: fileName,
            }));
            xhr.onload = function() {
                doUpload({
                    location: xhr.getResponseHeader("location"),
                    chunks: chunks,
                });
            };
            xhr.onerror = function() {
                console.log(xhr.response);
            };
        }).getAt();
    }

function doUpload(e) {
    var chunks = e.chunks;
    var location = e.location;
    var cnt = 0;
    var end = chunks.length;
    var temp = function callback(cnt) {
        var e = chunks[cnt];
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("PUT", location, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', e.range);
        xhr.send(e.data);
        xhr.onloadend = function() {
            var status = xhr.status;
            cnt += 1;
            console.log("Uploading: " + status + " (" + cnt + " / " + end + ")");
            $("#progress").text("Uploading: " + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%");
            if (status == 308) {
                callback(cnt);
            } else if (status == 200) {
                $("#progress").text("Done.");
            } else {
                $("#progress").text("Error: " + xhr.response);
            }
        };
    }(cnt);
}

function getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize) {
    var chunkPot = {};
    chunkPot.total = fileSize;
    chunkPot.chunks = [];
    if (fileSize > chunkSize) {
        var numE = chunkSize;
        var endS = function(f, n) {
            var c = f % n;
            if (c == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return c;
            }
        }(fileSize, numE);
        var repeat = Math.floor(fileSize / numE);
        for (var i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
            var startAddress = i * numE;
            var c = {};
            c.startByte = startAddress;
            if (i < repeat) {
                c.endByte = startAddress + numE - 1;
                c.numByte = numE;
                chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
            } else if (i == repeat && endS > 0) {
                c.endByte = startAddress + endS - 1;
                c.numByte = endS;
                chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
            }
        }
    } else {
        var chunk = {
            startByte: 0,
            endByte: fileSize - 1,
            numByte: fileSize,
        };
        chunkPot.chunks.push(chunk);
    }
    return chunkPot;
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index.html");
}

function getAt() {
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}

// This commented line is used for enabling Drive API and adding a scope
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".
// So please don't remove this.
// DriveApp.createFile();
```

---

index.html (edited with suggestion below; Code.gs is the same):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Resumable upload for Web Apps</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
    </form>
    <div id="progress"></div>

<script>
    const chunkSize = 5242880;

    $('#uploadfile').on("change", function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        if (file.name != "") {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.fileName = file.name;
            fr.fileSize = file.size;
            fr.fileType = file.type;
           fr.onload = init;
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
    });

    function init() {
        $("#progress").text("Initializing.");
        var fileName = this.fileName;
        var fileSize = this.fileSize;
        var fileType = this.fileType;
        console.log({fileName: fileName, fileSize: fileSize, fileType: fileType});
        var buf = this.result;
        var chunkpot = getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize);
        var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buf);
        var chunks = chunkpot.chunks.map(function(e) {
            return {
                data: uint8Array.slice(e.startByte, e.endByte + 1),
                length: e.numByte,
                range: "bytes " + e.startByte + "-" + e.endByte + "/" + chunkpot.total,
            };
        });
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(at) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&fields=mimeType%2Cid%2Cname%2CwebViewLink%2Cparents");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + at);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
                mimeType: fileType,
                name: fileName,
                parents: ["1xs9T_RfqZBS4i2JquCzy7qwumvrbPX4G"] // Please set the folder ID of the folder you want to upload.}));
            xhr.onload = function() {
                doUpload({
                    location: xhr.getResponseHeader("location"),
                    chunks: chunks,
                });
            };
            xhr.onerror = function() {
                console.log(xhr.response);
            };
        }).getAt();
    }

function doUpload(e) {
    var chunks = e.chunks;
    var location = e.location;
    var cnt = 0;
    var end = chunks.length;
    var temp = function callback(cnt) {
        var e = chunks[cnt];
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("PUT", location, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', e.range);
        xhr.send(e.data);
        xhr.onloadend = function() {
            var status = xhr.status;
            cnt += 1;
            console.log("Uploading: " + status + " (" + cnt + " / " + end + ")");
            $("#progress").text("Uploading: " + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%");
            if (status == 308) {
                callback(cnt);
            } else if (status == 200) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        var url = obj.webViewLink;
        console.log(url);
        $("#progress").text(url);
    } else {
                $("#progress").text("Error: " + xhr.response);
            }
        };
    }(cnt);
}

function getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize) {
    var chunkPot = {};
    chunkPot.total = fileSize;
    chunkPot.chunks = [];
    if (fileSize > chunkSize) {
        var numE = chunkSize;
        var endS = function(f, n) {
            var c = f % n;
            if (c == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return c;
            }
        }(fileSize, numE);
        var repeat = Math.floor(fileSize / numE);
        for (var i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
            var startAddress = i * numE;
            var c = {};
            c.startByte = startAddress;
            if (i < repeat) {
                c.endByte = startAddress + numE - 1;
                c.numByte = numE;
                chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
            } else if (i == repeat && endS > 0) {
                c.endByte = startAddress + endS - 1;
                c.numByte = endS;
                chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
            }
        }
    } else {
        var chunk = {
            startByte: 0,
            endByte: fileSize - 1,
            numByte: fileSize,
        };
        chunkPot.chunks.push(chunk);
    }
    return chunkPot;
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to upload a file to the specific folder and want to return the URL of the uploaded file.

From your showing script, if you are using [my script](https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps/blob/master/index.html) in https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps , when you want to upload a file to the specific folder, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify `init()` as follows.

##### From:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + at);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
mimeType: fileType,
name: fileName,
}));
```

##### To:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&fields=mimeType%2Cid%2Cname%2CwebViewLink%2Cparents");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + at);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    mimeType: fileType,
    name: fileName,
    parents: ["###folderID###"] // Please set the folder ID of the folder you want to upload.
}));
```

And, please modify `doUpload(e)` as follows.

##### From:

```
} else if (status == 200) {
    $("#progress").text("Done.");
} else {
```

##### To:

```
} else if (status == 200) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    var url = obj.webViewLink;
    console.log(url);
    $("#progress").text(url);
} else {
```

- By this modification, the file is uploaded to the specific folder and the webViewLink is returned.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Resumable Upload for Web Apps using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps)
- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

#### Added:

The following script is my tested script. **Before you use this script, please set your folder ID to `parents: ["### folder ID ###"]`.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Resumable upload for Web Apps</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
    </form>
    <div id="progress"></div>

<script>
    const chunkSize = 5242880;

    $('#uploadfile').on("change", function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        if (file.name != "") {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.fileName = file.name;
            fr.fileSize = file.size;
            fr.fileType = file.type;
            fr.onload = init;
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
    });

    function init() {
        $("#progress").text("Initializing.");
        var fileName = this.fileName;
        var fileSize = this.fileSize;
        var fileType = this.fileType;
        console.log({fileName: fileName, fileSize: fileSize, fileType: fileType});
        var buf = this.result;
        var chunkpot = getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize);
        var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buf);
        var chunks = chunkpot.chunks.map(function(e) {
            return {
                data: uint8Array.slice(e.startByte, e.endByte + 1),
                length: e.numByte,
                range: "bytes " + e.startByte + "-" + e.endByte + "/" + chunkpot.total,
            };
        });
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(at) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&fields=mimeType%2Cid%2Cname%2CwebViewLink%2Cparents");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + at);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
                mimeType: fileType,
                name: fileName,
                parents: ["### folder ID ###"] // <--- Please set your folder ID.
            }));
            xhr.onload = function() {
                doUpload({
                    location: xhr.getResponseHeader("location"),
                    chunks: chunks,
                });
            };
            xhr.onerror = function() {
                console.log(xhr.response);
            };
        }).getAt();
    }

    function doUpload(e) {
        var chunks = e.chunks;
        var location = e.location;
        var cnt = 0;
        var end = chunks.length;
        var temp = function callback(cnt) {
            var e = chunks[cnt];
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("PUT", location, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', e.range);
            xhr.send(e.data);
            xhr.onloadend = function() {
                var status = xhr.status;
                cnt += 1;
                console.log("Uploading: " + status + " (" + cnt + " / " + end + ")");
                $("#progress").text("Uploading: " + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%");
                if (status == 308) {
                    callback(cnt);
                } else if (status == 200) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
                    var url = obj.webViewLink;
                    console.log(url);
                    $("#progress").text(url);
                } else {
                    $("#progress").text("Error: " + xhr.response);
                }
            };
        }(cnt);
    }

    function getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize) {
        var chunkPot = {};
        chunkPot.total = fileSize;
        chunkPot.chunks = [];
        if (fileSize > chunkSize) {
            var numE = chunkSize;
            var endS = function(f, n) {
                var c = f % n;
                if (c == 0) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return c;
                }
            }(fileSize, numE);
            var repeat = Math.floor(fileSize / numE);
            for (var i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
                var startAddress = i * numE;
                var c = {};
                c.startByte = startAddress;
                if (i < repeat) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + numE - 1;
                    c.numByte = numE;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                } else if (i == repeat && endS > 0) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + endS - 1;
                    c.numByte = endS;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            var chunk = {
                startByte: 0,
                endByte: fileSize - 1,
                numByte: fileSize,
            };
            chunkPot.chunks.push(chunk);
        }
        return chunkPot;
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () ~~~
Refused to get unsafe header "location" ~~~
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 () ~~~
Uploading: 501 (1 / 1) ~~~

okay so i took the code from your git post and edited your above code, those are the errors that i am getting.

Comment: @Ameen Halawani Thank you for replying. About `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () Refused to get unsafe header "location" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 () Uploading: 501 (1 / 1) okay so i took the code from your git post and edited your above code, those are the errors that i am getting.`, I have to apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Ameen Halawani Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed modification, no error occurs. I deeply apologize that when I tested my modified script, no error occurs. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So, in this case, it is required to know the method for correctly replicating your current issue. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: You dont have to give an apology as i am worse than you. So ill go through it from 0. 
I created a project and started with the code.gs as usual, and created another project named index.html. the code is taken from your site here -> https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps   ~~ all i did was save deploy and use the script link. the error was given after submitting an upload. I hope i sounded clear as I suck at explaining. 
~edit: the project is executed as "me" and is accessed by "anyone"

Comment: I shall give it another test right away. I am human i might have missed a step..

Comment: @Ameen Halawani Thank you for replying. It's no problem. I would like to support you. When the same issue occurred again, please tell me. I would like to confirm it by correctly replicating your current issue.

Comment: okay so apparently, The code in your git page gives the same error above.
I went back to the script at the top of the page(question code) and it worked. i tried editing the suggestions u gave me on both the code from your page and the question code and the error came back.

Comment: may i ask if you where using the files other than index.html and code.gs? if u where, then this is my mistake. As all i used was the index and code.gs files.

Comment: @Ameen Halawani Thank you for replying. About `The code in your git page gives the same error above.`, can you provide your script reflected my proposed modification? About `may i ask if you where using the files other than index.html and code.gs? if u where, then this is my mistake. As all i used was the index and code.gs files.`, from your showing script, I use my sample script in https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps . So, I use only index.html and Code.gs. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Ameen Halawani By the way, I added my tested HTML and Javascript. Please confirm it. In that case, I think that you can use it by copying and pasting it.

Comment: okay i edited the post, the code i tried after your proposal is up there. the Code.gs is the same as the one at the very top(its unchanged).
 Where did you add your tested html and js?

Comment: @Ameen Halawani Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand whether you tested my added script. But, when I saw your added script, I think that `parents: ["1xs9T_RfqZBS4i2JquCzy7qwumvrbPX4G"] // Please set the folder ID of the folder you want to upload.}));` is not correct. Because})); is included in a comment line. I think that when you copied my script, you might have miscopied my script. I apologize for this. Can you confirm your script again and test it again? But, please don't worry. I confirmed that when this is modified, your script worked.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, I just copy pasted your code in the snippet. I still got the same error. This is weird. Have you made any change in the Code.gs?

Comment: @Ameen Halawani Thank you for replying. About `Hello Tanaike, I just copy pasted your code in the snippet. I still got the same error. This is weird.`, I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that in this case, it is required to know your actual Google Apps Script project to correctly replicate your current issue. Because when I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. I think that the reason for the no error is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for my poor skill. So, can you provide your actual Google Apps Script project? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Ameen Halawani About `Have you made any change in the Code.gs?`, I have never changed it. I deeply apologize that I have never changed it.

Comment: @Ameen Halawani By the way, although I have already mentioned in my answer, when you modified the script, did you reflect the latest script to Web Apps? When you didn't reflect your latest script in Web Apps, the issue cannot be removed. I'm worried about it.

Comment: Please stop apologizing, Im not better than you and there is always room for error in coding. When you mean reflect  the latest script to the web apps, do you mean deploy again? If so, then yes. I dont know much about git, but here are codes that i used. https://github.com/helleoo4/upload-apps-script.

Comment: @Ameen Halawani Thank you for replying. About your reply, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I'm worried that you might not be able to correctly understand my comment. In this case, the script is correct. I think that the reason for your current issue is due to your setting. So, in this case, I told that it is required to know your actual situation. So, can you share your sample Google Apps Script project? By this, I confirm it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.

Comment: here is the link to the code that is showing the error:  
https://script.google.com/d/10gLvEpbAgdENmBDBDzIA5Mda4Fv6utiLvYe8Oq2-4lRihuEW_rtt5n3f/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ameen Halawani Thank you for replying. When I tested your script, no error occurs. The file can be uploaded. So, in this case, as I have already mentioned in my answer, did you redeploy Web Apps for reflecting the latest script to Web Apps? I'm worried about it. If you didn't it yet, please redeploy Web Apps and test it again. At that time, if the URL of Web Apps is changed, please access the new Web Apps URL. I'm also worried about this.

Comment: i tried testing it again after redeploying it, the same error was displayed. I'm just as confused as you.

Comment: @Ameen Halawani Thank you for replying. About `i tried testing it again after redeploying it, the same error was displayed. I'm just as confused as you.`, I think that your script reflected my proposed modification is correct. So, in this case, how about creating a new Google Apps Script and copying and pasting the script and HTML and deploying it as Web Apps and testing it again?